# How to measure the RPM of a drone motor using Betaflight?

Tags: betaflight, brushless-motors, esc

I am interested in finding out the RPM of the motors on my drone with certain amounts of load and without load. Is there some way to measure the RPM of a drone motor using BetaFlight? If not, is there another way?

Not sure if it matters, but I am using the SucceX-E 45A 2-6S BLHeli_S Dshot600 4-in-1 ESC and some Xing-E 2207 2750kv motors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bi-directional DShot can help you here. After updating the BLHeli firmware on your ***BLHeli_32*** ESCs to the latest version (*support was added only recently*) and the firmware on your flight controller to Betaflight >4.0 (*[PR on Github](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/pull/7264)*), you can go into the Betaflight Configurator app and enable Bi-directional DShot under the `Configuration` tab.

It must be said that the easy BLHeli ESC firmware upgrade is only available for BLHeli_32 ESCs. There are ways to get support for bi-directional DShot on BLHeli_S ESCs, but they're more complicated. Instructions are linked to on the [Betaflight Wiki page](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/Bidirectional-DSHOT-and-RPM-Filter#bidirectional-dshot-firmware).

[image]

#### Motors tab in Betaflight Configurator

The ESC-reported motor RPM values will then be displayed under the `R` label next to each motor in the `Motors` tab.

[image]

#### OSD Widget

There is also an OSD widget for viewing motor RPMs, called `OSD_ESC_RPM` [in the code](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/blob/master/src/main/osd/osd.h), which can be enabled under the OSD tab.

#### BlackBox

As @BenWilson points out in his comment on this answer, you can also set the BlackBox debug mode to `DSHOT_RPM_TELEMETRY` and get motor RPM values recorded in your BlackBox log The implementation is described on the [Betaflight Wiki here](http://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/Debug-Modes).

Comment: In addition to this, you can set blackbox debug mode to DSHOT_RPM_TELEMETRY and get motor RPM values recorded in your blackbox log (I've never tried this, but it's mentioned here: https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/Debug-Modes)

Comment: @BenWilson That's a great point.